# The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. error occurred when posting job from my application

Tags: linkedin-api

I am getting error "**The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.** " when posting job using `Job API` from my application.

I found code from here:

http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/code-sample-posting-job-c.

Any idea where I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you're probably running into throttle limits.

https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/throttle-limits